# How to set specific data source for an active chart in PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to build a connection with an active PowerPoint presentation and specific sheet in a Workbook where my pivot table is. The xxlsm and xpptm files are open, in PowerPoint I'm adding a new slide to the end and I'm creating pie chart - ok, but then I want this pie chart to have reference of my Workbook and a specific sheet, not the default one.

My idea was to try ActiveChart.SetSourceData and try to replace with my Workbook and sheet "pivot" with range (A2:B7), or maybe any other options?

```vb
'adding new slide
Set NewSlide = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 11)

' Create the chart and set a reference to the chart data
Set myChart = ActivePresentation.Slides(ActivePresentation.Slides.Count).Shapes.AddChart.Chart

ActiveChart.ChartType = xlPie
ActiveChart.SetSourceData **Source:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4")**, PlotBy:= _
    xlColumns
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Sheet1"
ActiveChart.HasTitle = False
```

' it it possible to change bolted source to my Workbook and sheet "pivot" with range (A2:B7)? Or if not any other ideas of how to connect?

Answer (score 0):

Creating the pie chart in Excel then copy/pasting into PowerPoint links the chart.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim xlApp As Object, xlWK As Object
    Dim xlChart As Object, xlSht As Object
    Dim oSlide As Slide, sWorkBook As String
    sWorkBook = "Data.xlsm"   ' Update your workbook name
    Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    If Not xlApp Is Nothing Then
        Set xlWK = xlApp.Workbooks(sWorkBook)
        If Not xlWK Is Nothing Then
            Set xlSht = xlWK.Sheets("pivot")
            xlSht.Range("A2:B7").Select
            Set xlChart = xlSht.Shapes.AddChart2(251, xlPie)
            xlChart.Copy
            With ActivePresentation
                Set oSlide = .Slides.Add(.Slides.Count + 1, 11)
            End With
            oSlide.Shapes.Paste
            xlChart.Delete
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```